# alternate solutions to "JDA Member may not be null" error

Tags: java, eclipse, discord, discord-jda, jdal

I'm trying to make it so when someone with the role "Owner" types the mute command, it takes the person they @mentioned and gives them the "Muted" role.

The rest of the code works on it's own, the only part that is not working is the line

```
event.getGuild().addRoleToMember(member,event.getGuild().getRoleById(0)).complete();
```

and the variable "member" is defined by

```
Member member = event.getGuild().getMemberById(mentionid);
```

The full chunk of code is:

```
package radishmouse.FoodWorld.Events;

import net.dv8tion.jda.api.EmbedBuilder;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.entities.Member;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.events.message.guild.GuildMessageReceivedEvent;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.hooks.ListenerAdapter;
import radishmouse.FoodWorld.FoodWorld;

public class GuildMessageReceived extends ListenerAdapter {

    public void onGuildMessageReceived(GuildMessageReceivedEvent event) {
        String[] args = event.getMessage().getContentRaw().split("\\s+");
        
        if (args[0].equalsIgnoreCase(FoodWorld.prefix + "mute")) {
            if  (hasRole("Owner", event)) {
                if (args.length == 2) {
                    String mentionid = args[1].replace("<@!", "").replace(">", "");
                    Member member = event.getGuild().getMemberById(mentionid);
                    event.getGuild().addRoleToMember(member, event.getGuild().getRoleById(0)).complete();
                    EmbedBuilder msg = FoodWorld.sendMessage(null, "idk " + mentionid + member, "Blue");
                    event.getChannel().sendMessageEmbeds(msg.build()).queue();
                }
                else {
                    EmbedBuilder msg = FoodWorld.sendMessage("Specify Who To Mute", "Usage: " + FoodWorld.prefix + "mute [@mention who to mute]", "Blue");
                    event.getChannel().sendMessageEmbeds(msg.build()).queue();
                }
            }
        }
        
        /* If the bot ever sends a message, then add a ❌ reaction so users can delete that message */
        if (event.getAuthor().equals(event.getJDA().getSelfUser())) {
            event.getMessage().addReaction("❌").queue();
        }
    }

    private boolean hasRole(String string, GuildMessageReceivedEvent event) {
        Boolean toReturn = false;
        
        for(int i=0; i < event.getMember().getRoles().size(); i++){
            if("Owner".equals(event.getMember().getRoles().get(i).getName())){
                toReturn = true;
            }
        }
        
        return toReturn;
    }
```

For reference, I'm following this tutorial on youtube: [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CIDA1wOUf3k&t=307s).
I'm not the most familiar with JDA and don't know how this would be done in an easier way.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of parsing the string:

```java
  String mentionid = args[1].replace("<@!", "").replace(">", "");
  Member member = event.getGuild().getMemberById(mentionid);
```

Use [getMentionedMembers](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/entities/Message.html#getMentionedMembers()):

```java
List<Member> mentions = event.getMessage().getMentionedMembers();
if (mentions.isEmpty()) {
  EmbedBuilder msg = FoodWorld.sendMessage("Specify Who To Mute", "Usage: " + FoodWorld.prefix + "mute [@mention who to mute]", "Blue");
  event.getChannel().sendMessageEmbeds(msg.build()).queue();
} else {
  Member member = mentions.get(0);
  event.getGuild().addRoleToMember(member, event.getGuild().getRoleById(0)).queue();
  EmbedBuilder msg = FoodWorld.sendMessage(null, "idk " + member.getId() + member, "Blue");
  event.getChannel().sendMessageEmbeds(msg.build()).queue();
}
```

Comment: Thanks that worked! I just used: `mentions.get(0)` as the "member" in your code. Thanks <3